# "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'". I am developing garbage detector model and this is the error

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, tensorflow, numpy

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

model = './ C:/Parth/cs11/converted_keras/saved_model.h5'


data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

image = Image.open('C:/cs11/pic.jpg')

size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

image_array = np.asarray(image)

normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

data[0] = normalized_image_array

prediction = model.predict(data)
print(prediction)
```

And the error i am receiving is

```
  File "cs11.py", line 22, in <module>
    prediction = model.predict('data')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict
```

I  am not able to understand why it is happening so even if data is an `np.ndarray`. Could someone please tell me a way around this? Or an alternative method for it?

Comment: Add `model = load_model('./ C:/Parth/cs11/converted_keras/saved_model.h5')`

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you, you are trying to use the `predict` method on the `model` variable, but `model` is a string instead of a `tensorflow`/`keras` model which does not have this method. You therefore need to use `load_model` and pass it the location of the model file, which should return you a tensorflow model using which you can then use `predict`.